# Enqueue Google CDN jQuery in Footer

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to enqueue jQuery from Google's CDN and have it called in the footer rather than the header of my theme.

Here's my code:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js", false, '1.10.2', true);
```

I found a couple of potential solutions that don't work for me, they are:

1) Adding the following to my functions.php:

```
function ds_enqueue_jquery_in_footer( &$scripts ) {

if ( ! is_admin() )
    $scripts->add_data( 'jquery', 'group', 1 );
}
add_action( 'wp_default_scripts', 'ds_enqueue_jquery_in_footer' );
```

2) Calling wp_enqueue_scripts like so (as I'm doing above really):

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery','/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js','','',true);
```

No matter what I've tried, jQuery is called in the header. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

### The right hook

The [`wp_default_scripts`-hook](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6655f30fd9a00f9411db529df7ae7e1b6afb68bc/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php#L39) only runs in the admin as it's called by [`wp_default_scripts()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/77882e1c20b96c491ea589c7aac2faf57577a74f/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L50-520) on [`~/wp-admin/load-scripts.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/b95be39fbbb990dfcf51a4c3dc84cc4b5a770341/wp-admin/load-scripts.php#L136) where it's [hooked at the end of the file](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/77882e1c20b96c491ea589c7aac2faf57577a74f/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L958).

So to move jQuery in public to the footer, you have to use a different hook: `wp_enqueue_scripts`, which *only* runs in the public. No admin check needed.

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or exit;
/* Plugin Name: jQuery to the footer! */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wcmScriptToFooter', PHP_INT_MAX -1 );
function wcmScriptToFooter()
{
    $GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->add_data( 'jquery', 'group', 1 );
}
```

I'm using `PHP_INT_MAX`, the maximum nr your system/server/OS is capable of. It makes *very* sure that your action triggers last to ensure that all other hooks have run previously. Still, nothing is 100% secure when it comes to priorities, but you got a very fair chance that it will work out.

### Queueing the script

About your use of the `$_SERVER` superglobal: You should stay back from using that. Command line interfaces (short: CLI - like Git/GNU Bash, Shell, etc.) won't be able to retrieve data from there. That means that all automated test environments like PHPUnit or SimpleTest will fail as well as all cronjobs or runwhen jobs won't be able to get any data from it.

The nice thing is, that schemeless, relative URls work out in all major browsers across all major versions. That means that `//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js` will always give you the latest version.

```
function wpse124773_jQueryFromCDN()
{
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'jquery',
        '//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js',
        array(),
        0,
        true
    );
}
```

### The right version

If you stick with the "official" `latest` version, WP might choke on it. The reason is simple: Core doesn't constantly use the latest version. Now we need to ensure that we're always using the version that WordPress currently uses. To achieve that, we're going to *ask* WP which version the current one is. That means that our script will always stay in line and up to date with core:

```
function wpse124773_jQueryFromCDN()
{
    $version = $GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered['jquery']->ver;

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'jquery',
        "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/{$version}/jquery.min.js",
        $GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered['jquery']->deps,
        $version,
        true
    );
}
```